# python add extra column to existing csv and fill the column with empty values

Tags: python, csv

I have this CSV:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

I would like to add a 2 new headers and for each existing row add an empty value for this new column:

| "column1" | col2 | New1 | New 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "timestamp" | "N/A" |  |  |
| "N/A" | "string element" |  |  |
| 2 | "string" |  |  |

The flat CSV is comma separated:

```
"column1",col2
"timestamp","N/A"
"N/A","string element"
2,"string"
```

I tried this but it removes all the double quotes and the "N/A" values

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
df["New1"] = ""
outcsv=fileName
df.to_csv(outcsv, index=False)
```

The output is:

```
column1,col2,New1
timestamp,
,string element
2,string
```

but I would need this output:

```
"column1",col2,New1,New2
"timestamp","N/A",,
"N/A","string element",,
2,"string",,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code gives the desired output.

keep_default_na keeps the N/A. quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE keeps the quotes.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv as csv
fileName = "a.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(fileName,keep_default_na=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
df["New1"] = ""
df["New2"] = ""
outcsv = fileName
df.to_csv(outcsv, index=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: Nicely copy pasted from my answer, and doing the last bit of work, without giving any credit!

Comment: Sorry. But I didn´t read your answer until after writing my own answer. I guess we just wrote the same thing since it´s the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `keep_default_na=False`, otherwise the `"N/A"`s in the existing CSV gets recognised as `NaN`, which is then written as the empty string when you write out the new file.  Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileName, keep_default_na=False)
# do your thing
df.to_csv(fileName)
```

For more details, see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), particularly, read the options `keep_default_na` and `na_values`.

**EDIT:** to respond to the comment about quoting, I think it's a bit harder, because it seems to me the options are either you quote minimally, or quote everything, which is contrary to the requirement of having the new columns as empty string while retaining the original quotes.  I would play around with the `quoting` option in [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: thanks @suvayu it works. how can I keep also the double quotes in the output?

Comment: @ClaudioM That's a bit more difficult I think, see my edit